# Como indicar una tabla opcional en un esquema entidad-relacion

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un esquema entidad-relacion en LucidChart porque en un ejercicio piden que haga una bases de datos para una app de traduciones y se me ocurrio crear una tabla por cada idioma y usar como llave primaria un ID ademas de usar una tabla que sea donde se alojan las palabras en Español.
¿Como deberia indicar en el esquema respecto crear una tabla nueva por cada idioma de la traduccion? 
¿Deberia plantear el ejercicio de otra forma y alojar directamente todas las traducciones en otra tabla llamada "traducciones"?

Answer (score 0):

Hacer una tabla por idioma es un error. Necesitas una tabla de idiomas y una tabla de traducciones con una columna de idioma de origen y una de idioma destino.

Normalizando un poco más, puedes tener una tabla de palabras y asignar el idioma a cada palabra. Así, puedes dejar la tabla de traducciones simplemente como una relación entre palabras.